# Writing UInt16List via IOSink.Add, what's the result?

Tags: dart

Trying to write audio samples to a file.
I have List of 16-bit ints

`UInt16List _samples = new UInt16List(0);`

I add elements to this list as samples come in.
Then I can write to an IOSink like so:

```
IOSink _ios = ...

List<int> _toWrite;
_toWrite.addAll(_samples);
_ios.add(_toWrite);
```

or

`_ios.add(_samples);`

just works, no issues with types despite the signature of add taking `List<int>` and not `UInt16List`.

As I read, in Dart the 'int' type is 64 bit.
Are both writes above identical? Do they produce packed 16-bit ints in this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Uint16List` is-a `List<int>`. It's a list of integers which truncates writes to 16-bits, and always reads out 16-bit integers, but it is a list of integers.

If you copy those integers to a plain growable `List<int>`, it will contain the same integer values.

So, doing `ios.add(_sample)` will do the same as `ios.add(_toWrite)`, and most likely *neither* does what you *want*.

The `IOSink`'s `add` method expects a list of *bytes*. So, it will take a list of integers and assume that they are bytes. That means that it will only use the low 8 bits of each integer, which will likely sound awful if you try to play that back as a 16-bit audio sample.

If you want to store all 16 bits, you need to figure out how to store each 16-bit value in two bytes. The easy choice is to just assume that the platform byte order is fine, and do `ios.add(_samples.buffer.asUint8List(_samples.offsetInBytes, _samples.lengthInBytes))`. This will make a view of the 16-bit data as twice as many bytes, then write those bytes.

The endianness of those bytes (is the high byte first or last) depends on the platform, so if you want to be safe, you can convert the bytes to a fixed byte order first:

```
if (Endian.host == Endian.little) {
  ios.add(
      _samples.buffer.asUint8List(_samples.offsetInBytes, _samples.lengthInBytes);
} else {
  var byteData = ByteData(_samples.length * 2);
  for (int i = 0; i < _samples.length; i++) {
    byteData.setUint16(i * 2, _samples[i], Endian.little);
  }
  var littleEndianData = byteData.buffer.asUint8List(0, _samples.length * 2);
  ios.add(littleEndianData);
}
```